# How to apply HTTPS in a Reverse Proxy Multidomain in Docker

Tags: docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I am in a project in which we have decided to have several web servers in Docker, so we make use of a Reverse Proxy Multidomain (all requests to the same machine, and this with the proxy is already responsible for redirecting to the web container that indicates the request). All this works correctly, but when it comes to securing it with HTTPS (using our own certificates), it is not able to make the redirection (I've not created a DNS server yet, so I'm using the /etc/hosts file to do the translation).

As to work this with our structure is something complex, I have mounted a simple example which also fails to make the redirection to HTTPS.

Here is the structure:

[image]

And here are the files:

- reverse-proxy_simple/docker-compose.yml

  ```
  version: "3.2"
  services:
    proxy:    
      image: nginx
      container_name: proxy_examples
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
      volumes:
        - ./confProxy/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        - ./confProxy/ssl:/etc/nginx/certs/
        - ./confProxy/includes:/etc/nginx/includes/
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      networks:
        - examples  

    example1.com:
      image: php:7-apache
      container_name: example1.com
      ports:
        - 8081:443
      volumes:
        - ./example1/sites-available:/etc/apache2/sites-available/
        - ./example1/example1.com:/var/www/html/
        - ./example1/certs:/etc/ssl/certs/
      networks:
        examples:
          ipv4_address: 192.168.1.10

    example2.com:
      image: php:7-apache
      container_name: example2.com
      ports:
        - 8082:443
      volumes:
        - ./example2/sites-available:/etc/apache2/sites-available/
        - ./example2/example2.com:/var/www/html/
        - ./example2/certs:/etc/ssl/certs/
      networks:
        examples:
          ipv4_address: 192.168.1.20
    networks:
      examples:
        ipam:
          config:
            - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
  ```
- reverse-proxy_simple/confProxy (directory):

  - reverse-proxy_simple/confProxy/default.conf

  ```
  # web example1 config.
  server { 
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example1.com;

  # Path for SSL
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/certificate.key;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/certificate.ca.crt;
  include /etc/nginx/includes/ssl.conf;

  location / {
  include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
  proxy_set_header  Host $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwared-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
  proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
  proxy_pass https://example1.com/;
  proxy_read_timeout 600;
  proxy_redirect http://example1.com https://example1.com;
  }

  access_log off;  
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
  }

  # web example2 config.
  server { 
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example2.com;

  # Path for SSL
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/certificate.key;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/certificate.ca.crt;
  include /etc/nginx/includes/ssl.conf;

  location / {
  include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
  proxy_set_header  Host $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwared-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
  proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
  proxy_pass https://example2.com/;
  proxy_read_timeout 600;
  proxy_redirect http://example2.com https://example2.com;
  }

  access_log off;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
  }
  ```

  - reverse-proxy_simple/confProxy/includes (directory):

    - reverse-proxy_simple/confProxy/includes/proxy.conf

    ```
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    ```

    - reverse-proxy_simple/confProxy/includes/ssl.conf

    ```
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-   SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHAECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3- SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ```
  - reverse-proxy_simple/confProxy/ssl (directory)

    - certificate.crt
    - certificate.key
    - certificate.ca.crt
- reverse-proxy_simple/example1 (directory)

  - reverse-proxy_simple/example1/certs (directory)

    - certificate.crt
    - certificate.key
    - certificate.ca.crt
  - reverse-proxy_simple/example1.com (directory)

    - error.log
    - requests.log
    - public_html (directory)

      - index.html
  - reverse-proxy_simple/sites-available (directory)

    - 000-default.conf

    ```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.key
        SSLEngine on
    </VirtualHost>  
    </IfModule>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
    ```
- reverse-proxy_simple/example2 (directory)

  - reverse-proxy_simple/example2/certs (directory)

    - certificate.crt
    - certificate.key
    - certificate.ca.crt
  - reverse-proxy_simple/example2.com (directory)

    - error.log
    - requests.log
    - public_html (directory)

      - index.html
  - reverse-proxy_simple/sites-available (directory)

    - 000-default.conf

    ```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.key
        SSLEngine on
    </VirtualHost>  
    </IfModule>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
    ```
- /etc/hosts

  ```
  192.168.1.10  example1.com
  192.168.1.20  example2.com
  ```

Let me know if you know whats wrong here!
Thanks ;)